# Output of a absolute value function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the book Theory of computation by Michael Sipser.
"**For example, the absolute value function ${\text{abs}}$ takes a number $\boldsymbol x$ as input and
returns $\boldsymbol x$ if $\boldsymbol x$ is positive and $\boldsymbol {-x}$ if $\boldsymbol x$ is negative. Thus $\text{abs}\boldsymbol{(2)}\boldsymbol = \text{abs}\boldsymbol{(-2)} \boldsymbol{=
2.}$**". But absolute value function always give positive output then how does the book tell that function $\text{abs}$ returns $x$ if $x$ is positive and $-x$ if $x$ is negative. How is that even possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that if $x$ is already negative (for example $x=-5$) then $-x$ is **positive**. $-x=5$. So the definition is correct; it always returns a non-negative number.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're confused. You do know that if $x$ is negative then $-x$ is positive?

Comment: Why is this a set theory question?

Answer (score 0):

> But absolute value function always give positive output then how does the book tell that function abs returns x if x is positive and -x if x is negative.

If I am interpreting your query correctly, it actually represents two questions:

1. If (for example) abs($x$) = 2, what are the possible values of $x$?
2. How do you know that if abs($x$) = $s \times x$, where $s \in \{1, -1\},$ then when $x > 0, s = 1$ is used and when $x < 0, s = -1$ is used?

---

Answers

1. It is clear from the definition that abs($x$) = $s \times x$, where $s$ is either -1, or +1.  Therefore, if abs($x$) = 2, then $x \in \{2, -2\}.$
2. Since the absolute value function always returns a non-negative number, when $x > 0$, the scalar that is applied must be $s = 1$, rather than $s = -1.$

   Similarly, when $x < 0$, the scalar that is applied must be $s = -1$.  Otherwise, the result would not be non-negative.